# Hide/Show Input's based on mysql data

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an active session in my page using: `$_session_start();` I want to hide part of my form and show another based on the users previous entries.

Basically I offer **Direct Deposit** and **Paper Check** I want to be able to have the user only see the fields required for them to complete previously (in signup so the values are already in the database)

Right now the database table is set up like this:

paper_check with a value of 1 (yes pay this way) or 0 (no pay this way)

and the same thing with direct deposit. I need a way to show/hide the fields associated with each based on the users previous selections.

I typed this up but it doesn't seem to do anything. Please help me!!!!! (The class names hide and show are in my css and working properly!)

```
<?php 
    if ($_SESSION['direct_deposit'] == 1)
    {
      $doc->getElementById('check_payable_to')->className+" hide";
    }
    else
    {
      $doc->getElementById('name_on_account')->className+" hide";
      $doc->getElementById('check_payable_to')->className+" show";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: That syntax doesn't set the class of the elements. You need to call a setter method.

Comment: What DOM library are you using? It looks like the one on php.net, but it doesn't mention a `className` property.

Comment: I had pulled the script off google. I am not very skilled in php if I could do it in javascript and get the $_SESSION to work I would already have it done i'm sure. So if it's completely wrong i'm sorry. PHP has not been a huge thing in my career!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a `className` property in the PHP DOM library. It looks like this is the way to add a class to an element:

```
$doc->getElementById('check_payable_to')->setAttribute('class',
   $doc->getElementById('check_payable_to')->getAttribute('class') . " hide");
```

Do you have error reporting enabled? It should be warning about the unknown property.

If you want to do this in Javascript instead of PHP, have your PHP do something like:

```
<script>
var direct_deposit = <?php echo $_SESSION['direct_deposit']; ?>;
if (direct_deposit == 1) {
   /* Do what you want */
} else {
   /* Do what else you want */
}
</script>
```

Comment: Same results. nothing :( I really wish I had a stronger knowledge of php. Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: Ok, I got it with this and some playing around with my code. I simlply added two divs and wrapped them around each sections and then assigned them id's and went from there. Do we have a place where I could post my final answer is this all I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you said "I have an active session in my page using: $_session_start();" You shouldn't use $_session_start(). It should be session_start() .

Comment: That is correct and I am using $session_start(). I did not notice that I had typed it wrong in the question. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: I went back and looked it is typed like: session_start() in the first line of code. Thanks though ;)

Answer (score 0):

className+" hide" should be className .= " hide"

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping each section in it's own div like so:

```
<div id="paperCheck class="show"> 
   <!--Your Paper Check Information here-->
</div> 

<div id="directDeposit" class="show"> 
   <!--Your Direct Deposit Information here--> 
</div>
```

And then by using javascript you are able to do the following:

```
var direct_deposit = <?php echo $_SESSION['direct_deposit']; ?>;

if (direct_deposit == 1) 
{
   document.getElementById('paperCheck').className ="hide";
} 
else 
{
   document.getElementById('directDeposit').className ="hide";
}
```